# hasOwnproperty becomes undefined when used with multer for multipart data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

My code is as shown below:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var user = require('./../model/user');
var path = require('path');
var upload = multer();
var awsUpload = require('./../config/fileUpload.js');
var Promise = require('promise');
var item = require('./../model/items.js');
var item_image = '';

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './public/images')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        item_image = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
        callback(null, item_image)
    }
});


var itemAdd = function(req, res) {
    upload = multer({
        limits: {
            fileSize: 1000000,
            files: 1
        },
        storage: storage,
        fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
            var ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
            if (ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
                return callback(res.end('Only images are allowed'), null)
            }
            callback(null, true);
        }
    }).single('item_img');
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        var foodtruck_id = req.body.foodtruck_id;
        var newItem = new item();
        var itemList = [];
        newItem.item_name = req.body.item_name;
        newItem.item_tag = req.body.item_tag;
        newItem.item_description = req.body.item_description;
        newItem.item_category = req.body.item_category;
        newItem.item_discount_price = req.body.item_discount_price;

        for (var key in req.body) {
            if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (key == 'item_illustrations') {
                    newItem.item_illustrations = req.body[key];
                }
            }
        }
        newItem.item_stock = req.body.item_status;
        newItem.item_price = req.body.item_price;

        if ((foodtruck_id) && (foodtruck_id.trim() != '')) {
            foodtruck.findById(foodtruck_id.trim(), function(err, foodtrucks) {
                if (err)
                    res.json({
                        status: '500',
                        message: 'There is no data available'
                    });

                newItem.save(function(err, savedItem) {
                    if (!err) {
                        foodtrucks.item_list.push(savedItem._id);
                        foodtrucks.save(function(err, truck) {
                            foodtruck.find({
                                _id: truck._id
                            }).populate('item_list').exec(function(err, foodtrucks) {
                                res.json({
                                    status: '200',
                                    message: 'New item added successfully',
                                    data: foodtrucks
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.json({
                            status: '500',
                            message: 'Error while saving new item'
                        });
                    }
                });


            });

        }
    });

};
```

app.js

```
app.post('/test',itemAddition);
```

Now what happens here is, when I use **req.body.hasOwnProperty** with x-www-formurlencoded, it works fine, but whenever I am adding it with multer (multipart-data), it gives me **req.body.hasOwnProperty** is not a function. Is there any way with which this thing can be solved?

Comment: Don’t use `hasOwnProperty` on objects where all the keys are controlled by user input. That’s why it was made a prototype-less object. Instead, `key in req.body`

Comment: what do you get in `req.body` contents in console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`req.body` is a prototype-less object: it was created with `Object.create(null)` and so doesn’t inherit `hasOwnProperty` from `Object.prototype`. This is a *good* thing, because if a user passed a field named `hasOwnProperty`, they would be able to break your code.

Use the `in` operator instead, generally:

```
if (key in req.body) {
```

But in the case of the loop, you just don’t need a check at all:

```
for (var key in req.body) {
    if (key == 'item_illustrations') {
        newItem.item_illustrations = req.body[key];
    }
}
```

And in this particular case, just get the value you want without a loop at all:

```
newItem.item_illustrations = req.body.item_illustrations;
```

Comment: from postman, I am passing item_illustrations[0],item_illustrations[1] and so. Will this kind of functionality work with your solution?

Comment: @MrugeshThaker: Dunno, give it a try, it might.